# Reduce RAM usage when running Bert Extractive Summarizer in python

Tags: python, spacy, ram

When running Bert Extractive Summarizer in a RAM constrained environment [978M of RAM] (with the en_core_web_sm spaCy model), the program returns **Killed** as the result. I have been able to confirm that RAM is the likely culprit, as it tops out right before **Killed** is returned. Below is a simple test that I ran that resulted in **Killed** as the returned value.

```
from summarizer import Summarizer

body = '''
The Chrysler Building, the famous art deco New York skyscraper, will be sold for a small fraction of its previous s>The deal, first reported by The Real Deal, was for $150 million, according to a source familiar with the deal.
Mubadala, an Abu Dhabi investment fund, purchased 90% of the building for $800 million in 2008.
Real estate firm Tishman Speyer had owned the other 10%.
The buyer is RFR Holding, a New York real estate company.'''

model = Summarizer()
result = model(body, ratio=0.1)
print(result)
```

I can confirm that the code runs perfectly in an 8+ GB RAM environment (it would probably run similarly in 4+ GB, but I haven't confirmed that). I believe the next step would be for me to reduce the program's RAM usage, though I do not know how to do that. Is it possible for RAM usage to be reduced enough to allow the program to run in a less than 2 GB RAM environment? (And if yes, how can it be done?)

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's a way you can get that working. BERT/Transformer models are typically huge, and then you need memory for the documents and base models... Maybe  there's a tiny BERT-like model you can use but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @polm23 thank you. Is there an alternative to this or should I give up the idea of running extractive AI in such a resource constraint environment?

Comment: You should look at non-Transformers models, probably older ones. They'll typically work on much less powerful hardware and you should have options.

Comment: @polm23 Thank you. I will look into them and see if I can use any of them for my project. If not, then I will work on another solution that may bypass this issue.